# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am getting this error while i try to build an adroid project in IntelliJ IDEA (Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File)how can i fix it :
[image]

Comment: Can't see the error; post the image, not a link.  I'm guessing that you are using Maven but IntelliJ can't find the JAR in the repositories you've asked it to look in.

Comment: Just click the 'Install repository...' link in the error message.

Comment: just click on  Install Repository and sync project.

Answer (score 5):

Click on the "Install Repository and sync project" link.

Or you can try to fix your build.gradle manually.
Add this in build.gradle in the project's root directory:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // add below
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it ,  in android studio it worked but in IntelliJ nothing seems to be happening

Comment: can you add both of your build.gradle files to the question?

Comment: is this a good idea to solve the problem? shouldn't we remove the '+' after '27.' and replace it with a full version number?

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle 4.1+ you can use the following (used by Android Studio 3.0.1):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // add below line
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why Intellij IDEA doesn't prepopulate this dependency as it does with Android Studio (will raise a bug and reference it here shortly), but Google's Maven repository is required as it contains the Android libraries, see [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven).  Please upvote [IDEA-187121](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187121) (bug I raised on YouTrack), if you want to see this fixed.

[@Gavriel's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995235/4430939) of clicking "Install Repository and sync project" doesn't work at least with IDEA 2017.3.4.  The suggestion to include "maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }" does work for projects using all gradle versions, but is quite verbose.